# What Do You Call Someone Who Is Being Represented?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume Joe is sent to represent Sarah in a meeting. What would Sarah be to him? I'm looking for a more informal context, so it wouldn't be a client.

Comment: Joe is Sarah's _proxy_, which is the antonym of what you're looking for. I don;t think there's a word for this. Just use 'Sarah', or if the person isn't known it would be 'The person who John is representing'.

Comment: I just deleted the answer I posted, because I realized afterwards that the question is about the person being represented and not the representative. Sorry -- my mistake.

Comment: If Joe and Sarah have a professional relationship, Sarah might be Joe's *client*

Comment: Sarah is the principal, but how informal can the setting be with Joe *representing*? If too formal, let her represent herself.

Comment: @IsabelArcher that's exactly what I'm looking for. I want the person being represented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered archaic, but there's always [representee](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/representee).

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/representee):

**representee**
(ˌrɛprɪzɛnˈtiː)
NOUN
1. (in contract law) a person to whom a legal representation ( statement of fact concerning a contract) is made
2.  archaic: a representative, esp in a parliament
**3.  archaic: a person who is represented**

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot more terms for Joe -- representative, stand-in, agent, deputy, etc. -- than for Sarah.

The terms for Sarah are less common and less informal.  For instance, the term "principal" is used for her when discussing the "principal-agent problem" but that's rather technical.

Most references to the person being represented, in my experience, would describe it as something like "Joe is speaking for/representing/standing in for Sarah" rather than saying "Joe is Sarah's [term]"